# How to get integrated values from np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numerical-integration, acceleration

I am trying to get integrated values from np.array, list of values. Not the surface under the function, but values. I have values of acceleration and want to get values of velocity.
So let's say I have an arry like:

```
a_x = np.array([111.2, 323.2, 123.3, 99.38, 65.23, -0.19, -34.67])
```

And I try to get integrated values from this array to get the values of velocity.

If I use lets say simps, quad, trapz, I get the one number (surface).

So how do you integrate np.array values and get integrated values that you can store in a list?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by the way you want it, because you didn't understand the process behind it. If you are given acceleration, then using the following equation:

[image]

You are able only to find INDEFINITE integral, you know the acceleration, but you don't know starting conditions, thus your solution can't be empty.

As the solution to each of those questions is: "Find velocity given an acceleration", then the solution would be v(t)=integral of a(t)dt+c, where your acceleration is constant, so it doesn't rely on t and it can be written as v(t)=at+c, but still - we don't know anything about how long acceleration lasted and what is the starting condition.

But answering the question about getting values which can be stored in a list - you do it by indexing your values of np.array:

```
import numpy as np
a_x = np.array([111.2,323.2,123.3])
#Gets first value
print(a_x[0])
```

> If I use lets say simps, quad, trapz, I get the one number (surface).

Because quad,simps,or trapz are methods used for given points, which return value of integral with those given points with corresponding method, for example:

```
numpy.trapz(y, x=None, dx=1.0, axis=- 1)
```

if x isn't specified (as in your case), it assumes that you want to use trapeze to estimate the field under the value y of given points with x equal distribution of x. It has to give one value.

Comment: Well I wasn clear. I have the np.array of acceleration, but also the np.array of time values. So its not about indefinite integral but definite. The thing is that I need to get values of velocity form integrating np.array of acceleration over np.array of time.

Comment: Then in loop you create numpy.trapz() as y you pass each next time the acceleration and as x you pass the time, changing the dx value to be smaller (however in this case it doesn't matter, since all will be counted as a big rectangle if I understand your code)

Comment: Well my goal is to get values of velocity. I have the np array of acceleration: a_x = np.array([111.2, 323.2, 123.3, 99.38, 65.23, -0.19, -34.67]), and I have the np.array of the time: time = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]). I want to get the values of velocity, also as array, so I can use those values in graph, plt.plot(time, velocity)

Comment: You also need staring velocity value array, or we assume it is 0. (But we can't, because there are negative acceleration.)

Comment: the strating velocity would be zero, cuz the starting time is zero

Comment: It doesn't mean starting velocity HAS to be zero then. The time=0 is relative to starting measure, the velocity can be not zero then. It would make sense for negative acceleration.

Comment: Yes it can not be zero. But theoretically, if you have a function a(t), and you integrate it over dt, every part of that function gets to be multiplied by t, and if you integrate it from t_first to t_last, and the t_first is zero, the whole equation becomes zero. But I dont think this is relevant in my case anyway.

Comment: I guess you don't get the idea of computing integral here then. You don't multiply by time, but by periods of time, to make it more accurate, you make smaller pieces of time, as in "dt" which corresponds to t->0 in limit. Then, if your steps are half a second, then you multiply by 0.5 ALL the time and sum the constant acceleration * 0.5s over needed period. Thus, if we assume all velocities in t=0 are 0, then we get:
v(t)=at, where your time is always 2.5s. However, check what happens when your velocity is -0,19, then we are going backwards, since our starting velocity was 0 at the beggining.

Comment: So, it makes no sense that starting velocity is 0 in all of those cases. Anyway, to count what the integral will show with your assumptions, multiply all velocities by 2.5

Comment: I was just giving an example earlier of np.array of acceleration. I acctually do have different np.array. I just want to know how to get values of integration if you have acceleration as np.array and time as np.array. If I multiply all acceleration values with my step, I will get a results with to big of a mistake.